# Need help identifying what type of obfuscation is this

Tags: javascript, obfuscation, deobfuscation

This is my first time seeing javascript that is obfuscated like this, script ran normally through frida.

```
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
```

```
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
```

Thats only part of the code, I took some from the top and bottom, Since pasting it all here is not possible.

Full script https://paste.md-5.net/eguhedizey.coffeescript

I've tried deobfuscating it like regular base64 (obviously doesn't work)